# Reflection vs. Map<List<String>> etc. etc

Tags: java, reflection, annotation

Random question:
Tengo un JSON de un montón de kilobytes, ya casi llegando al mega.

Estoy por convertirlo en algo Java-istico y estoy entre un mapa de listas: `Map<List<Map<List, OMG>>>> data`

O una clase hecha y derecha:

`Departamento { 
        Empleado { 
            Direccion {
                String calle;
            }
        }
  }`
 
Etc. etc

La cuestión esta que hay que acceder algunas propiedades dinámicamente dependiendo de la interacción del usuario (ejemplo hay un combo con departamentos y si escoges RRHH pues ese ese si es Conta etc.)

Con el mapa hago

`Map<List<Map, ETC>>> depa = data.get( depaSeleccionadoPorElUsuarioEnUnCombo );`

Con la clase tendría que usar reflection… verdad? verdad?

`for ( Field f : data.getClass().fields ) { 
    if ( f.getName() == depaSeleccionaroporElusuarioEnUNCombo ) {
      String value = f.invoke( o, whacha whacha);
   }`

Puedo usar anotaciones pero el tema es el mismo

Pregunta: Con todo y todo,  es significativamente más rápido / lento usar un clase concreta y luego reflection para acceder el contenido   O es mejor user el mapa de listas de mapas de listas de listas de mapas de etc. etc.

Estoy empezando a hacer una prueba de concepto para esto, pero si alguien ya ha pasado por ahí y tiene alguna información que avise.

Answer (score 0):

Se ve muy feo usar reflection en ese caso. No se trata tanto de eficiencia de ejecución sino en calidad de código (y por lo tanto claridad, mantenimiento, debugging, testing, etc).

Si tu supermapa tiene una estructura fija, conocida de antemano, entonces en general conviene hacer una clase. Más todavía si la alternativa es un montón de colecciones genéricas (mapas y listas) muy anidadas. Pero no entiendo porqué tendrías necesidad de usar reflection. Si conoces por qué campo estás buscando el dato (o,  en la estructura mapa de listas, en nivel de profundidad) entonces no deberías tener necesidad de usar reflection.

Comment: Es que no sé que campo voy a usar, se determina en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: No entiendo a lo que llamas "campo". Si se tratara de algo así como nivel de profundidad en el mapa-de-listas-de-mapas, siempre sería mas prolijo un `if`o un `switch`. Pero, repito, no termino de entender tu escenario.

Comment: Tu lo llamaste campo. Lease: atributo/field/propiedad/variable de instancia. 

Imagina que tienes un combo box que dice: "Seleccione el departamento `["rrhh", "contabilidad", "ingenieria"]`  Dependiendo de la selección quieres ver el contenido. Digamos que la selección está en la variable `departamento = userSelection(["rrhh", "contabilidad", "ingenieria"]);` 
Si uso un `Map<String,String> map`  podría escribir: `map.get(departamento)`  Si uso una clase tendría que ser `if departamento == "rrhh" return data.getRhhh() else if departamento == "contabliidad"  return data.getContabilidad()`

Answer (score 0):

Antes que usas reflection (tal cual por claridad y rendimiento) tuviera más sentido de usar un `AttributeSet` - básicamente un ´Map` de atributos.

Si lo encuentras necesario de restringir las claves puedes usar constantes en tu imlementación y implementar una validación en de los argumentos en los métodos `getAttribute(Object o)` y en los métodos en que agregas atributos, posiblemente tirando una excepción personalizada.